# Finding the Bias and Residual Components of Mallows Cp

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, model

So I have this question but am unsure on how to do it:

If  a  true quadratic  regression  function  is $E(Y) = 15+20X+3X^2$,  and  the  fitted  linear  regression function is $\hat{Y}=13+40X$, for which $E(b_0) = 10$ and $E(b_1) = 45$.  What are the bias and sampling error components of the mean squared error for $X_i=10$ and $X_i=20$.

So I know that Mallows Cp is divided into two parts, the bias and residual part.

The equation for bias is: $Bias = E(\hat{y_i}) - \mu_i$

And the equation for the residual is: $\text{Random error} = \hat{Y_i} - E(\hat{y_i})$

For the residual error I know you just have to find the difference between the $E(Y)$ and the $\hat{Y}$ equations for $x = 10$ and $x = 20$.

However I am unsure on how to calculate the bias, mainly as I do not know what to do with the $E(b_0)$ and $E(b_1)$ terms. I do not know how to find the mean $\mu_i$.

If someone knows how to do this please let me know, as I am rather confused on the methodology to do this.

Thank you for your time.